# Determine whether array holds an almost increasing sequence

Tags: javascript

Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.

For sequence = `[1, 3, 2, 1]`, the output should be

```
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) === false
```

There is no one element in this array that can be removed in order to get a strictly increasing sequence.

For sequence = `[1, 3, 2]`, the output should be

```
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) === true
```

As you can remove 3 from the array to get the strictly increasing sequence `[1, 2]`. Alternately, you can remove 2 to get the strictly increasing sequence `[1, 3]`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  //compare current int to previous, return true if greater than 
  //remove int at index and compare with new values, return false if comparison fails
  var result = false;

  for(var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++){
     var newSequence = sequence.slice();
     var subSequence = newSequence.splice(i, 1);

     for(var j = 0; j < newSequence.length - 1; j++){
        if(newSequence === newSequence.sort((a,b) => a < b).reverse()){
          result = true;
        } 
     }         
  }
  return result;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this problem. I feel like I'm very close but for some reason when I call reverse in the conditional statement it also sorts out the newSequence variable. It's sorting two variables in the conditional, not one. As a result it resolves to true. I'm not clear why this is happening. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: `newSequence.sort()` modifies the array, it doesn't return a new array.

Comment: The comparison function in `sort` should return `-1`, `0`, or `1`, your function returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: `reverse()` also modifies the array in place.

Comment: You can't compare the contents of arrays using `===`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to use a nested loop, nor to create new arrays. This can be done in *O(n)* time:

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
    var prev = -Infinity,
        beforePrev = -Infinity,
        allowExceptions = true;
    
    for (var curr of sequence) {
        // Is order not maintained?
        if (curr <= prev) {
            // Give up when this is not the first exception
            if (!allowExceptions) return false;
            allowExceptions = false;
            // Decide whether to skip the current or previous value
            if (curr > beforePrev) prev = curr;
        } else { // Normal case: keep track of two preceding values
            beforePrev = prev;
            prev = curr;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1,5,3,4,8])); // true
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1,5,0,6,8])); // true
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1,5,0,4,8])); // false
```

Comment: This answer is fantastic, super simple and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`sort()` modifies the array in place, it doesn't return a new array. And you can't compare the contents of two arrays using `==`, so that's not a good way to tell if an array is sorted. You can simply loop through the array, testing if each element is greater than the previous one.

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
    var newSequence = sequence.slice();
    newSequence.splice(i, 1);
    var isSorted = true;
    for (j = 1; isSorted && j < newSequence.length; j++) {
      if (newSequence[j] <= newSequence[j-1]) {
        isSorted = false;
      }
    }
    if (isSorted) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2, 1]));
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2]));
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3]));
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([8, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: Originally I was using a nested loop to compare `newSequence[j] < newSequence[j + 1]` which would return true for any values meeting this criteria. I dont know how to write a conditional that states only if the entire array is in order.