# How do I see if an array is the same as another array & why does trying to see if they are === change the first array into the second array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, comparable, array-splice

This is the first time I've ever tried to write any code, so please give me a break if what i did makes no sense & please explain what's going on. i've never taken a class or anything, just read a couple books, so i would appreciate it if you could explain things. i'm trying to do this problem(instructions are as follows);

> Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array

so, this is what i did:

```
function almostIncreasingSequence (sequence) {
  for(x=0; x < sequence.length; x++) {
    var y = sequence[x];
    sequence.splice[x,1];
    if (sequence === sequence.sort(function (a, b) {return a > b})) {
      return sequence
    } else {
      sequence.splice[x,0,"y"]
    }
  }
}
```

it wasn't returning what i wanted when i put true and false as returns where they should go, so i replaced the true with sequence and removed false to see what was happening. this is just what i did to see what it returned, so i knew where to go from there. i'm not asking for the answer. i am confused as to why it returned what it did. why does this always return the sequence sorted & compared(numbers in order from least to greatest)? that shouldn't be the answer, unless it should return 'true'. what i expected was that it would remove each element of the array, one at a time, check if it is in order, then put it back, if not. i chose to `{return sequence}` just to see what the sequence ended up doing & only return it in order for the ones where the answer should be true. again, i figured it would check to see if the sequence(now missing the element sequence[x]) was equal to the sequence sorted from most to least `(sequence === sequence.sort(function (a,b){return a>b}))`, then return `'true'` if it is, or replace the array[x] if not. then start over, but it just returns the array from least to most every time. why isn't that 4th line isolated? instead of just seeing if they're equal with each other, it obeys the command and changes the whole sequence definition. like if i were to  write:

```
function almostIncreasingSequence (sequence) {
  for (x=0; x < sequence.length; x++) {
    var y = 1;
    var x = 3;
    if(x === y + x) {
      return x
    } else {
      return y
    }
  }
}
```

this doesn't return `y+x`, it always returns `y`, so why does the first example return `sequence.sort(function (a,b){return a>b})` every time? i realize it sorted the "sequence" and then "sequence" became `sequence.sort(function (a,b){return a>b})`, but why? it was inside an `if` statement and was supposed to see if they were `===`, not make sequence `=` to the sorted & compared sequence. it's not like, in the second example, `x` became `y+x`. what's is going on here? why does saying `if(sequence === sequence.sort(function (a,b){return a>b}))` actually `array.sort[compare function]` the sequence when it's only supposed to see if they're equal??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please also visit the [help] and read up on [ask] when you can, so you know what to do in the future.

Comment: @Patrick Roberts thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `sort` method returns the same array object as you apply the `sort` method on, not a *new* (sorted) array. The array itself is sorted, and so the original order is lost. This is called *in-place* sorting. So `x.sort() === x` is *always* true for any array `x`, independently on how it is sorted. The comparison is on the object (array) reference, and that reference does not change during the sort.

So there are two issues which play at the same time:

- `sort` alters the array it is called on. If you want to get a sorted version of the array *without* affecting the original array, then you must first take a copy, for instance with `slice`:

  ```
  sequence.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b)
  ```

  Now `sequence` will not be sorted, but the expression will return a sorted copy of it. If you would then continue like this:

  ```
  const sortedSeq = sequence.slice().sort((a,b) => a - b);
  if (sequence === sortedSeq[i]) then // ...etc
  ```

  ... the condition will *never* be true, even if the original array already was sorted. See next point:
- When `arr1` and `arr2` are arrays, comparing their contents is not as simple as `arr1 === arr2`. That will just tell you whether they are the same object (array) reference. If they are, then their contents are by consequence equal, but the opposite is not true: if two arrays are different references, then it is not implied that their elements are the same and in the same order. For that you must compare the elements itself, which for instance you can do with `every`:

  ```
  const sortedSeq = sequence.slice().sort((a,b) => a - b);
  if (sequence.every( (a, i) => a === sortedSeq[i] ) then // ...etc
  ```

  *That* was what you thought you were doing.

---

Note that the challenge you are working on has been presented on StackOverflow before. See [Determine whether array holds an almost increasing sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168005/determine-whether-array-holds-an-almost-increasing-sequence/47168233#47168233)

Comment: i tried to explain but it said it was too long. i split it up into several below

Comment: right, i know i was all over the place, so it seems like you didn't understand my question. i'll try to clarify better. also,  i looked at all the other questions and they didnt say anything about what i am asking. as i said, i am not looking for the answer to the problem, i am looking for the answer to my questions about why it returned a sorted array, and how to see if the array is the same(as in every element in the same `array[#]`) as a sorted array instead of equal to it. what i don't understand is why it returns a sorted sequence every time.

Comment: i never actually sorted it as far as i can tell;  i just tried to see if the sequence was equal to a sorted sequence, but it shouldn't have been, so it should have replaced and returned to the beginning. if the answer should be false, this code would return null as far as i know. it obviously doesn't, but i want to understand why it returned what it did. i get that `x.sort() === x` but by asking `if(x.sort() === x)` it actually sorted x. why?  here is the array i put in `2, 4, 11, 1, 6, 8` and it returned `1, 4, 6, 8, 11`, which it should have just returned the array, not the array sorted.

Comment: that's why i mentioned the second example, because it doesn't return the if statement as an executed command. it didnt change `x` into `y+x`, but the first one changed `array` into `array.sort()`. also, would `x.sort() === x` be true if we were using _words_ or just _numbers_?

Comment: i understand numbers are equal because of unicode, but what about letter or words?  what i don't get is why it took out `sequence[x]` then returned the array sorted even though i wrote `return sequence`. why wouldn't it return the original sequence minus `sequence[x]`, instead of the sequence sorted minus `sequence[x]`, like it did? i didn't want it to sort the array, just compare the array to a sorted array., then if they were equal, return the original array

Comment: @Scott Marcus help me out, please

Comment: You started with `it seems like you didn't understand my question`. He totally understood it, and answered it. The sort method, as already explained, is an _in-place_ algorithm. Imagine if you were to do something like this: `function edit(o){o.b=3;return o}var a={};console.log(a===edit(a));console.log(a);`. You know that it will log `true` and `{b:3}`, since it's the same object but it's been changed. `array.sort()` is the same thing, it sorts and returns the same `array` object.

Comment: There are methods that leave their object alone, and there are functions that don't: `sort` belongs to the second group: it touches the array. It sorts `sequence`. If you output the array elements of `sequence` before and after that call, the output is different. It does not matter whether you call it in an `if` condition or as a statement. `sequence` will have been sorted.

Comment: Updated my answer with much more detail. I hope it clarifies it for you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, comparing a reference to an array with itself will, of course, return `true`.

Your `variable` is an object. Forget for a moment that it is an array and stuff. This object has a method (function) attached, `sort`. So even if you call that method, the object is still the same. That is why comparing `arr` === `arr.sort(sortMethod)` gives back true.

Now, to the problem at hand. You need to find if there is more than one element of your array that isn't bigger the one before. Here is something relatively simple, there are a few ways for you to optimize it. But in very simple, explicit terms (without error checking and stuff):

```
function isAlmostIncreasing(sequence) {
  // Hold a reference to our joker card
  let joker = false;
  // Start counting from the second array element (index = 1).
  for (let i = 1; i < sequence.length; i++) {
    // compare previous and current elements:
    const current = sequence[i];
    const previous = sequence[i - 1];
    if (!(current > previous) {
      // uh-oh! current integer is not bigger than the previous one!
      if (!joker) {
        // Phew! We can use our joker!
        joker = true;
      } else {
        // Oh, darn. Joker is used up, this is now the second bad element.
        // We might as well give up and let people know this is not a good sequence.
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  // Well, if we are here, it means we're good, right?
  return true;
}
```

We achieved the goal, though - we determined if it is possible to make a strictly increasing sequence. We did not modify the array in the process, so the owner can still use it for their purposes (e.g. check if he can do the strictly decreasing thing). There are a few things we could do differently, maybe a bit better, I will leave them to you. Here is a basic algorithm, go play with it.

Comment: thanks, i thought i understood why they were equal, but i didnt until that explanation, but i still don't get why it returned a sorted sequence even though i asked it to just return the sequence. how did it get sorted? or why? i tried to explain it better in the comments to the other guy

Comment: Did you call `sort` in the mean time? Probably, as a side effect.